# How to add list of list and list?

Tags: apex, list

this is my list of list

```
((VEC209_ALGE, 2751282.05), (VEC232_ALGE, 2557264.96),
(VEC209_ALGE, 2.0), (VEC232_ALGE, 2.0), 
(VEC209_ALGE, 160000.0), (VEC232_ALGE, 120000.0),
(VEC209_ALGE, 3379000.0), (VEC232_ALGE, 3112000.0), 
(VEC209_ALGE, 3219000.0), (VEC232_ALGE, 2992000.0))
```

this is my another list

```
(PVCHT, TAUX1, TVAHRK, PVCDEM, PVCTTC)
```

I want my output:

```
((VEC209_ALGE, 2751282.05,PVCHT), (VEC232_ALGE, 2557264.96,PVCHT), (VEC209_ALGE, 2.0,TAUX1), (VEC232_ALGE, 2.0,TAUX1), (VEC209_ALGE, 160000.0,TVAHRK), (VEC232_ALGE, 120000.0,TVAHRK), (VEC209_ALGE, 3379000.0,PVCDEM), (VEC232_ALGE, 3112000.0,PVCDEM), (VEC209_ALGE, 3219000.0,PVCTTC), (VEC232_ALGE, 2992000.0,PVCTTC))
```

each List(0) should added with List of list(0) and (1)
List(1) added with list of list(2) and (3)

any one give me some idea !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider list1 is your List of List and list2 is your second list from which you want to copy values.
You can do the following to get required output:

```
i = 0, j = 0;
for(i=0; i < list1.size(); i+=2) {
    list1[i].add(list2[j]);
    list1[i+1].add(list2[j]);
    j++;
}
```

Before using this you should be sure that every time for a List of List of size n there will be another list of size n/2 from which you want to add values to first list.
Also you may have to add error handling in the above snippet.

Edit (For variable count value):

```
i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
count = 3;  // This value may change
for(i=0; i < list1.size(); i+=count) {
    for(j=i; j<(count+i); j++) {
        list1[j].add(list2[k]);
    }
    k++;
}
```

See if this works.

Comment: Thank you for the answers.It helps me a lot.I need some more clarification. listref size is always 5 listref=((PVCHT, TAUX1, TVAHRK, PVCDEM, PVCTTC)) listPriceref is a List<list<string>> .This size differs. listPriceref=((VEC209_ALGE, 2751282.05,PVCHT), (VEC232_ALGE, 2557264.96,PVCHT), (VEC209_ALGE, 2.0,TAUX1),........) I have to map the listref(0) to ListPriceref(size) Eg:If size is 5 i have to map listref(0) to ListPriceref(0,1,2,3,4) listref(1) to ListPriceref(5,6,7,8,9) this can be done ???!!!

Comment: How do you want to distribute those 5 values in listref to lists in listPriceref? Is there any rule which defines how these 5 values will be distributed? @uma

Comment: I mean, In your example, how is size = 5 decided?

Comment: lisref size is always 5.it's somewhat like predefined.the listref values may change but size is 5.I want distribute those 5 values to lists in listPriceref.depending upon some integer count.Is it clear.                             ex:integer count 3 listref(0) added to LIstPriceref(0),LIstPriceref(1),LIstPriceref(2)     then listref(1) added to LIstPriceref(4),LIstPriceref(5),LIstPriceref(6)    If integer count 4 Listref(0) added to LIstPriceref(0),LIstPriceref(1),LIstPriceref(2),LIstPriceref(3)      here count is some integer value

Comment: updated the answer @uma

Comment: if the count =2 ,listref(0) is added to LIstPriceref(0),LIstPriceref(1) correctly and added to LIstPriceref(2)  also .then it stops .listref(1),(2),(3),(4) are not distributed.I don't know y..Please help me out@Azinq

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35742/discussion-between-uma-and-azinq).

Answer (score 0):

1. Loop through the first list.
2. Get the index
3. Fetch the same index data from second list (say tmp)
4. Append the tmp to list in the index of first list

**Edit:**

```
    for (Integer index = 0; index < firstList.size(); index++) {
        List<Object> tmp = firstList.get(index);
        tmp.add(secondList.get(index));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one and do some modification.

```
List<List<String>> wew= new List<List<String>>();
List<String> wew2= new List<String>();
wew.add(new List<String>{'VEC209_ALGE', '2751282.05'});
wew.add(new List<String>{'VEC232_ALGE', '2557264.96'});
wew.add(new List<String>{'VEC232_ALGE', '120000.0'});
wew.add(new List<String>{'VEC232_ALGE', '3112000.0'});

wew2.add('PVCHT');
wew2.add('TAUX1');
Integer x = 1;
for(List<String> hehe : wew) {

    if(math.mod(x,2) == 0){
        hehe.add(wew2[0]);        
        System.debug('The Final Result' + hehe);
        wew2.remove(0);
    } else {
         hehe.add(wew2[0]);        
        System.debug('The Final Result' + hehe);
    }
    x++;

}
```

Comment: Are you assuming **'2751282.05'** will be stored as String inside wew.add(new List<String>{'VEC209_ALGE', '2751282.05'}); ?

Comment: @karthikselva Based on the given example, Yes.  But that is only an example. I just want to show some possible way to solve his problem.

Comment: Thank you for the answers.I need some more clarification.                    listref size is always 5 listref=((PVCHT, TAUX1, TVAHRK, PVCDEM, PVCTTC))
listPriceref is a List<list<string>> .This size differs.
listPriceref=((VEC209_ALGE, 2751282.05,PVCHT), (VEC232_ALGE, 2557264.96,PVCHT), (VEC209_ALGE, 2.0,TAUX1),........)
I have to map the listref(0) to ListPriceref(size)  Eg:If size is 5 i have to map listref(0) to ListPriceref(0,1,2,3,4)
 listref(1) to ListPriceref(5,6,7,8,9) this can be done ???!!!

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
List<List<String>> mList= new List<List<String>>();
mList.add(new List<String>{'VEC209_ALGE', '2751282.05'});
mList.add(new List<String>{'VEC232_ALGE', '2557264.96'});
mList.add(new List<String>{'VEC209_ALGE', '2.0'});
mList.add(new List<String>{'VEC232_ALGE', '2.0'});
mList.add(new List<String>{'VEC209_ALGE', '160000.0'});
mList.add(new List<String>{'VEC232_ALGE', '120000.0'});
mList.add(new List<String>{'VEC209_ALGE', '3379000.0'});
mList.add(new List<String>{'VEC232_ALGE', '3112000.0'});
mList.add(new List<String>{'VEC209_ALGE', '3219000.0'});
mList.add(new List<String>{'VEC232_ALGE', '2992000.0'});
Integer counter = 0;
Integer mcounter = 0;
List<String> mList2 = New List<String>{'PVCHT', 'TAUX1', 'TVAHRK', 'PVCDEM', 'PVCTTC'};
    for (List<String> mLString : mList){
        counter += 1;
        if (counter ==1){
             mLString.add(mList2[mcounter]);
        }
        if (counter ==2) {
            mLString.add(mList2[mcounter]);
            counter =0;
            mcounter +=1;
        }
        system.debug(mLString);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use 2 Dimensional List instead:

```
List<List<string>> arrayOfReportData = new List<List<string>>();
    for(Integer i=0; i<3; i++){
        arrayOfReportData.add(new List<String>{'MyValue1', i});
    }
```

The Output will be : ((MyValue1,0), (MyValue1, 1), (MyValue1, 2))

Follow the link for more details:

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000005GOrIAM

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.